# Can't figure out how to pass struct array to function

Tags: c++, arrays, function, structure, header-files

I have a header file, main cpp file and functions file and am trying to pass a stuct array from the main function to the functions file and can't figure out the syntax.  I have stripped the code done to show what I am doing without showing hundreds of lines of code.

I have tried every variation i know of to pass the structure array and it won't compile; I have read everything I could find on it and can't find the solution; I know it is just a syntax thing I'm not figuring out.

**header.h file**

```
#ifndef myHeader_h
#define myHeader_h


#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>


using namespace std;


struct MyStruct
{
    float var1;
    float var2;
    float var3;
};

struct MyStruct2
{
    string var4;
    string var5;
    bool var6;
    MyStruct struct1;
};


int enterFunction(int maxNumber, int & currentNumber, structList);

#endif
```

**Main Program**

```
#include "myHeader.h"

int main()
{
    int currentNumber = 0, maxNumber = 0;

    MyStruct *structList;
    structList = new MyStuct[maxNumber];

    enterFunction(currentNumber, maxNumber, structList);
    return 0;
}
```

**Functions file**

```
#include "myHeader.h"

int enterFunction(int maxNumber, int & currentNumber, structList)
{
// DO MORE STUFF HERE
}
```

Comment: What error message are you getting? That should help you identify your issue.

Comment: You pass array of size 0 to the function (which can't resize it) ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your header.h file, instead of

```
int enterFunction(int maxNumber, int & currentNumber, structList);
```

you need

```
int enterFunction(int maxNumber, int & currentNumber, MyStruct * structList);
```

And in your Functions file, likewise you need

```
int enterFunction(int maxNumber, int & currentNumber, MyStruct * structList)
```

And that's it!

By the way, it is dangerous to put `using namespace std` (or any `using` directive) in a header file like that. It might break other people's code if they have to include your header. Better to put it in your `C` file. (And even if nobody is ever going to include your header, it's a bad habit to get into.) See [this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/167862/428857).

Comment: Compiled perfectly!  That's what I needed.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of error-prone manual memory management you should use [RAII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_acquisition_is_initialization) to manage resources. C++ has `std::vector` for this and it makes life a lot easier. I guess that the function `enterFunction` should read a number of structs from a file or the keyboard, so the task would be to create a list of input values. You can pass a reference to the vector:

```
int enterFunction(int maxNumber, int & currentNumber, std::vector<MyStruct2>& structlist);
```

However, I would change the signature to return the vector with the input values. This makes the function easier to comprehend and reason about:

```
std::vector<MyStruct2> enterFunction(int maxNumber) {
    std::vector<MyStruct2> inputs;
    // let's assume that >> is overloaded for MyStruct2
    while (inputs.size() < maxNumber) {
        MyStruct2 x;
        cin >> x;
        inputs.push_back( std::move(x) );
    }

    return inputs;
}
```

Please note that this will not copy the vector as the return value because it uses named return value optimization.

Comment: When done with a `std::vector` like this, both `maxNumber` and `currentNumber` are probably unnecessary.  That's one of the reason `std::vector` rocks!

Comment: I agree vector rocks, but for the user requirements of this program it has to be an array of structures (not my choice).  :-)

Comment: @RockRat You can pass a pointer to the vector's data to legacy code or C code. This is one of the use-cases for vector.